# How to build .rptproj (SSRS project) without using devenv.com?

Tags: reporting-services, msbuild, devenv

I need to build the SSRS project (.rptproj) without using devenv utility. I have used devenv to build from command line but can not use the same on build server as it is not having Visual Studio. Is there any way we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible. The `rptproj` project type uses a pre-msbuild project format that is only understood by VS and built via it's installed components.